# facebook api для трансляции facebook-отзывов на своем сайте

Tags: php, api, facebook

Есть сайт компании. Есть страничка компании на facebook.
Нужно подтягивать отзывы fb-странички на наш корпоративный сайт. Это возможно? Прочел документацию по Facebook Graph API и Graph SDK, но мало что понял. Мне нужно не делать постоянно http-запросы, а чтобы данные подтягивались на сайт автоматически после их публикации на фэйсбуке

Comment: в итоге нашли решение?

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear нет